# Modify IIS web.config using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm trying to modify the web.config using PowerShell.

So far, I'm able to replace the Connection String using:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "IIS:\Sites\$Name\WS" -filter "connectionStrings/add[@name='Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings.DirectoryConnectionString']" -name "connectionString" -value "Server=SERVERNAME\INSTANCE1;Database=ProductDirectory.$Name;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

this works OK.

Now, I want to change something in the applicationSettings part of the web.config.
The Part looks like:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogLevel" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Info</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogDirectory" serializeAs="String">
        <value>D:\temp</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogSpecialTroubleshoot" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogSqlQueries" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogPerformance" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogXmlInput" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogXmlInputSeperate" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="EnableCatchAllLogging" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DirectoryDatabaseName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>ProductDirectory</value>
      </setting>
    </Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings>   
</applicationSettings>
```

I would like to change the "DirectoryDatabaseName" node.

Using:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "IIS:\Sites\$Name\WS" -filter "applicationSettings" -name "test" -value "ProductDirectory.$Name"
```

I can change the "root" node (applicationSettings) and add an attribute with name "test" to it.
However, if I'm trying to go "deeper" into the structure, I get the following Error:

```
WARNING: Target configuration object 'applicationSettings/Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='DirectoryDatabaseName'] is not found a
t path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/TestM/WS'.
```

I'm using the following PS for that:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "IIS:\Sites\$Name\WS" -filter "applicationSettings/Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='DirectoryDatabaseName']" -name "test" -value "ProductDirectory.$Name"
```

Not even this works (same error):

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "IIS:\Sites\$Name\WS" -filter "applicationSettings/Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings" -name "test" -value "ProductDirectory.$Name"
```

So somehow it stops working "one level below" `applicationSettings`

Also, how would the syntax be to change the text between `<value>` and `</value>`?

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me when editing a web.config file in a virtual directory of the default website and trying to view and change the appSettings section:

```
#List all appSettings
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "iis:\Sites\Default Web Site\VirtualDir" -filter "/appSettings/add" -name *

#Update specific appSetting
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "iis:\Sites\Default Web Site\VirtualDir" -filter "/appSettings/add[@key='SomeKey']" -name value -Value "SomeValue"
```

This assumes a standard web.config appSettings section like so:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <appSettings>
        ...
        <add key="TestKey" value="TestValue"></add>
        ...
    </appSettings>
    ...
</configuration>
```

In your case, the value is stored as a text node instead of an attribute, so the full xpath would be `/applicationSettings/Product.Core.WebServices.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='DirectoryDatabaseName']/value/text()` however I cannot find any example of web.config files with values stored as text nodes. The examples for the [IIS cmdlets](http://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/archive/2012/11/12/examples-of-iis-powershell-cmdlets.aspx) also don't show any references to text().

You may have to set the filter to retrieve the settings element, and then set it to a value element with the correct text. Again the examples don't show how to do this, but they do show how to use a hashtable to set multiple values, so you may be able to find a way to make it work.